# Network Admin "You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page."

Tags: permissions, password, network-admin

I have had trouble logging into WP-Admin with my admin account.

I have reset my password, and I can now log-in to WP-Admin, but cannot reach Network Admin (/wp-admin/network), instead receiving "You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page."

What do I need to do to restore the permissions the account had before the password reset?

Comment: I have exactly the same problem since 4 days. but no solution... Please help us !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest way to restore Super Admin privileges is to add a bit of code to your theme's `functions.php` file to add yourself back:

```
include(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/ms.php');
$user = get_userdatabylogin('YOUR_USERNAME');
grant_super_admin($user->ID);
```

Once your Super Admin privileges have been restored you can remove this code from your theme.

Comment: I receive an error "Call to undefined function grant_super_admin() in /.../wp-content/themes/.../functions.php on line 47.  I placed the code at the end of functions.php

Comment: Sorry, I clearly didn't test the code first! I edited the answer to fix your error. It should work now.

Comment: Hi Sam.  It's been a long time.  I'm having the same problem again.  I tried the solution, and Wordpress Admin prompted me that I have to upgrade the network.  After that, I  still receive "You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page." at /wp-admin/network

Comment: From [this post](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/no-networksuper-admin-after-enabling-network?replies=4), I re-uploaded wp-config.php, and the problem went away.  Looks like I had not correctly uploaded the updated wp-config.php.